# Why are complex numbers allowed to be combine like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdxJc.png)

This expression is meant to be simplified. Why does it make sense to write $$\frac{1}{1-6i} - \frac{1}{1+6i} = \frac{1+6i−(1−6i)}{(1−6i)(1+6i)} \quad ?$$

How can the rules followed here be applied to similar problems?

Comment: Read the easy directions to write mathematics in this site. For one, using above/below fractions writing, as $\;\frac1{1-6i}\;$ for example, will make things much easier to understand that slanted slash $\;1/(1-6i)\;$

Comment: i altered your fractions on the left to give you an example of how to format, but your RHS is incomprehensible, can you alter it into readable form that is mathematiccally equivalent of the LHS to make your point?

Comment: The same as $\frac 1a-\frac 1b=\frac {b-a}{ab}$

Comment: All of the elementary rules of arithmetic apply equally well to complex numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you simplify
$$
\frac{1}{1-6i}-\frac{1}{1+6i}.
$$
You multiply the numerator and denominator of each fraction by the conjugate of the complex number (change the sign of the part with $i$).  In other words, you have
$$
\frac{1+6i}{(1+6i)(1-6i)}-\frac{1-6i}{(1+6i)(1-6i)}=\frac{1+6i}{1+36}-\frac{1-6i}{1+36}=\frac{12i}{37}.
$$
This is your right-hand-side. (the original post had a very different RHS).

Answer (score 1):

> $$\frac{1}{1-6i}-\frac{1}{1+6i}$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-6i}\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{(1+6i)}{(1+6i)}}-\frac{1}{1+6i}\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{(1-6i)}{(1-6i)}}$$

$$=\frac{1+6i}{37}-\frac{1-6i}{37}=\frac{1+6i-1+6i}{37}=\boxed{\frac{12}{37}i}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, when $z\in\mathbb{C}$:

- $$\overline{z}=\frac{|z|^2}{z}\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{\overline{z}}=\frac{z}{|z|^2}$$

  ---

Now, in your example, set $z=1+6i$:

$$\frac{1}{\overline{z}}-\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z}{z\overline{z}}-\frac{\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}=\frac{z-\frac{|z|^2}{z}}{z\cdot\frac{|z|^2}{z}}=\frac{z-\frac{|z|^2}{z}}{|z|^2}=\frac{z}{|z|^2}-\frac{1}{z}$$

And so:

$$\frac{1+6i}{|1+6i|^2}-\frac{1}{1+6i}=\frac{1+6i}{37}-\frac{1-6i}{37}=\frac{1+6i-1+6i}{37}=\frac{12i}{37}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{1}{\overline{z}}-\frac{1}{z}
=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{z\overline{z}}
=\frac{2Im(z)}{|z|^2}
=\dfrac{12i}{37}
\qquad\text{for} \ z=1+6i
$$